# Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator + to types Duration and Number

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get Planned % complete on data date from Planned Start/Finish Date using if function

[image: power query table]

```
if ([Plan_Actual_Start_Date]> [Data Date]) then 0 else ((([Data Date]-[Plan_Actual_Start_Date])+1/(([Plan_Actual_Finish_Date]-[Plan_Actual_Start_Date])+1)))
```

I get an error as below

[image: error]

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatypes are important in Power Query.

When you subtract one date from another, the result is a duration data type.

In order to add a number to a duration, you can first convert the duration to a number.

Modify your formula segments to something like:  `Duration.Days([Data Date]-[Plan_Actual_Start_Date]) +1`